# Is it natural to use "difficult" about a person?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, idiomatic-language

This is said by an idiot husband in a story I'm writing:

> Don't mind her. She's just got her period. That's why she's a little *difficult*.

Is it perfectly natural to use "difficult" about a person?

Comment: Yes, just know it is very rude. Especially if it is said for this reason.

Comment: @maxbear123 I heartily disagree.  It's not *rude* at all.

Comment: @RonJohn It’s contextually rude. In the exact example it’s very likely to be taken as very rude no matter where you are, but more because of mentioning the reason the individual in question is being difficult (the particular reason quoted is a _very_ touchy subject in many English speaking cultures).

Comment: @maxbear123 the question is about being *difficult*, not about saying someone is "on the rag".  Andrew Tobiko's answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @RonJohn It is not rude to say to a friend about someone who is not present, but it certainly would be very rude to say directly to someone, or around the person you are talking about. To clarify, it would only really be rude in a workplace setting or if you said it to someone you did not know. I should have been more specific originally.

Comment: @maxbear123 I stand by my statement about Tobiko's answer (which has examples of "in person" usage of *difficult*.

Comment: It's the third of three definitions for *difficult*. What's unnatural to this urban American, given the subject matter, is not using the B word instead.

Comment: @maxbear123 I wouldn't say it's **very** rude to say directly to a person. It is blunt though. I would say Mazura's suggestion is **very** rude. So much so that "difficult" is polite in comparison. In the end it all comes down to cultural differences.

Answer (score 12):

If someone is difficult, they are hard to manage, uncooperative, troublesome. It's fairly common.

> “Oh, you are **so difficult**!” she told him, irritated.

> **Stop being difficult** and eat your broccoli—you know it's good for you.

You can also say

> a difficult **person**/**man**/**woman**/**child**

as in

> His wife is **a very difficult woman**.

There is a lot of literature on how **to deal with** difficult people:

> **Understanding** and **Working** with Difficult People
>
> **Managing** Difficult People in a Week
>
> How to **Get Along with** Difficult People

Interestingly, [there seem to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficult%20husband_INF%2Cdifficult%20wife_INF&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cdifficult%20husband_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdifficult%20husband%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdifficult%20husbands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cdifficult%20wife_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdifficult%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdifficult%20wives%3B%2Cc0#t3%3B%2Cdifficult%20husband_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdifficult%20husband%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdifficult%20husbands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cdifficult%20wife_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdifficult%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdifficult%20wives%3B%2Cc0) more difficult **husbands** than difficult **wives**.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As a native speaker of British English I would use this expression quite frequently.  In my mind it's another way of saying "he/she is difficult to deal with". A person who frequently causes problems or argues with others would be a 'difficult person'.

Answer (score 3):

It's common to use "difficult" as a euphemism for frustrating or irrational.
I imagine that both of these characters find the other rather difficult at times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to describe a person as 'difficult' or their behaviour as 'being difficult' is perfectly correct and idiomatic English.